# Can LASSO still perform regularization on summarized data?

Tags: modeling, descriptive-statistics, regularization, glmnet

Currently, we are trying to predict future revenue from existing users. We use the revenue collected after 14 days of membership to predict 3 year membership.  We train the model and make predictions on the level of cohorts (groups of users joining on the same day).  Hence, the outcome being modelled is the average revenue per user in the cohort.

We would like to introduce country as a variable for stratification.  Naturally, some countries have fewer members than others, and it would be great to use LASSO to shrink coefficients from countries with fewer users (and hence larger noise).

We have the number of users per cohort, and could use that as the sample weight in `glmnet`.  Alternatively, we could go back and compute the sample variance of revnue collected within each cohort.

In either case, will this produce the regularizing behaviour I'm looking for when the data are summarized rather than on the grain of user?

Comment: Sure, that should be doable, you'd just have to weight observations (or use offsets) appropriately so that it makes sense. E.g. log(Sales / users ) = explanatory variables + error can re-expressed as as log-sales ~ explanatory variables + error - log(users) (i.e. minus log-users offset).